# A better SSMS?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, sql-server-2008

I have a database that I need to edit a lot of fields on, but SSMS doesn't quite seem to be up to the task.  First problem is that I can't seem to insert multiple lines of text into a field.  Second is that any time I happen to have the Shift key held down when I press the space bar, SSMS immediately enters the data.

Is there a better application to just edit table/view data?  I need to be able to edit certain fields with multiple lines of text, and most notably, I need to be able to use TAB characters.  I've tried MS Access (which handles the multiple lines beautifully, but can't seem to handle the tabs.)

Alternatively, if someone can identify how I can use MS Access to enter TABS in a text field, that would work to.

Answer (score 1):

[Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) touts itself as a replacement for SSMS. You might like to try that to see if it suits you.

Answer (score 0):

Have to tried ALT or CTRL modifier on the tab key in Access? I cna't myself, sorry.

Otherwise, there are other SQL tools like SQuirreL that may do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a row with TAB character in it, copy it & paste it into next rows, when you need it :)

You could use VBA to enter a row with TAB in it & then use the TAB character from that row into other rows.

Alt + F11
Ctrl + G (immediate window)

```
CurrentDb.Execute "insert into table1 (x) values ('a" &  vbtab & "b')"
```

Here table1 is the name of the table & x is the text column (used to show an example).
The above statement executes an INSERT and sets the value of x to "a    b"

Alternatively

```
CurrentDb.Execute "insert into table1 (x) values ('a' & CHR(9) & 'b')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the tried the one specific for ms-access? It works better then the migration wizards built into ms-access, and ALSO works better then the SSMS tools for visual studio.

You can find it here:

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/migration-access.aspx

There is a version for both 2005, and 2008

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Excel to input the data, and then use the SSMS Import Data function to import the data?

Right click on the database in the Object Explorer and go to Tasks / Import Data.